# Where I can find master secret?

Tags: kinvey

In kinvey console I can open the app and click on the 3 dots and I can find app key and app secret but I can not find master secret so where I can find master secret ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies if my earlier comment was not clear to you. Please check following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Kinvey console, navigate to Setting-> Environment  Settings-> API keys and you will find Master Secret there.

Thanks,
Pranav
Kinvey

Comment: I  can not find the settings where it is ?>